# Is there an identifier in Linux for the current boot?

Tags: linux, identifier, reboot

My application needs to know if the system has rebooted since the last time it was run.  The current strategy I have is to persist a reboot ID that I generate with the following command:

```
last -f /var/run/utmp | egrep '^reboot' | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Linux kernel exports a unique identifier after each boot:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id
a30d49a3-612e-1132-a2b7-c34r01c5ed1r
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save a timestamp on every start. You could check uptime to see if the system came up before or after the last start time stamp

Have a look here too:
https://serverfault.com/questions/255911/detecting-restart-since-last-run-in-a-shell-script-on-linux